# How to fix Ionic Photo Viewer gradle compiler error?

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework, build, capacitor, photoviewer

So I wasted so many hours trying to simply add the photoviewer to my ionic angular app.

The steps seems simple.

```
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/core
$ npm install com-sarriaroman-photoviewer (this way cause I am using capacitor)
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/photo-viewer
```

I faced so many problems simply installing it because of the rxjs version. Whatever, that supposedly got resolved without having to use the force option.
Then I run `ionic build; npx cap sync android; npx cap open android` because on the browser complains that I am using a cordova native component and can't work it. That's fine, my phone should be able to handle it. However when android studio is building the gradle it throws this

> 13:55 Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. (16 s 923 ms)

What am I missing? It shouldn't be this hard to add a simple photo viewer!

There is nothing in the ["official page"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com-sarriaroman-photoviewer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally figured this out. So my gradle is up to date but it seems the com-sarriaroman module isn't. In its "photoviewer.gradle" file, it had

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

which is unreadable by the new version of the gradle builder. I replaced "compile" with "implementation" and it worked. However, someone needs to let them know and update their module. I know I shouldn't be the one messing with anything in node_modules.